# How to Set Conditional Payload in Reducer React Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, reducers

I have created app context with `useReducer()` and `useContext()` hooks in my application, controlling the `favourites` state (favourite images) in my application. The screen with favourites is just showing the list of items that the user has saved previously from another screen (hence im using `Context`).

The way I manage it is that on `ScreenA` I have a button for each image to add it to favourites. `ScreenB` monitors the changes in the context (`favourites`) and shows the contents of it.

My reducer has basically 2 (two) functions: `ADD_FAVOURITE` and `DELETE_FAVOURITE`. However, I want to also implement `REPLACE_FAVOURITE` which will run when the user refreshes the screen (`RefreshControl`). However, I can't add such action because the type of the payload cannot be an array.

Here is an example of my reducer:

```
export type FavouritesItem = {
    created_at?: string;
    id: number;
    image: ImageType;
    image_id?: string;
    sub_id?: any;
    user_id?: string;
};

export const favouritesReducer = (
    state: FavouritesItem[],
    action: { type: string; payload: FavouritesItem }
) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ContextTypes.Delete:
            return [
                ...state.filter((product) => product.id !== action.payload.id),
            ];
        case ContextTypes.Add:
            return [
                ...state,
                {
                    created_at: action.payload.created_at,
                    id: action.payload.id,
                    image: action.payload.image,
                    image_id: action.payload.image_id,
                    sub_id: action.payload.sub_id,
                    user_id: action.payload.user_id,
                },
            ];
        case ContextTypes.Replace: //return action.payload or smth
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

I would imagine that I could use conditional payload something like this:

```
action: { type: string; payload: FavouritesItem | FavouritesItem[] }
```

but that would be wrong because the properties of payload are not part of the array payload.

What can I do in this case? How to avoid setting up a new reducer and add replace action here?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have different payloads for different actions, then Define an action type like this

```
enum ContextTypes {
  Add,
  Delete,
  Replace
}

type Action = 
    | { type: ContextTypes.Add, payload: FavouritesItem }
    | { type: ContextTypes.Delete, payload: FavouritesItem }
    | { type: ContextTypes.Replace, payload: FavouritesItem[] }
```

This can convey that, we use different payload for different actions.

then, for the reducer, use the action type of our definition of Action

```
export const favouritesReducer = (
    state: FavouritesItem[],
    action: Action
) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ContextTypes.Delete:
            return [
                ...state.filter((product) => product.id !== action.payload.id),
            ];
        case ContextTypes.Add:
            return [
                ...state,
                {
                    created_at: action.payload.created_at,
                    id: action.payload.id,
                    image: action.payload.image,
                    image_id: action.payload.image_id,
                    sub_id: action.payload.sub_id,
                    user_id: action.payload.user_id,
                },
            ];
        case ContextTypes.Replace: 
            // Something like this depending on your need
            return [...state, ...action.payload]
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Comment: This seems to be working with a set up. I will try to run replace function and will let you know!

p.s. I would appreciate if you show your `ideal` way too, im curious how to make things better in this case.

Comment: @denistepp if you need a global state that holds fav pics, You may not need to replace on each reload. ( unless you want to clear everything ). If you have api calls (fav list needs to be taken from server ) it will be good to dispatch within useEffect inside context. Either way, if multiple action requires multiple payload.. You can implement Action like this.

Comment: @denistepp Ideally, I'd use two hooks, one to fetch data and then pass  the result it as initial state to the reducer. First hook would prepare data and the result will be passed as initial to the reducer.

Comment: I was thinking to add AppLoading method that would update the initial context before the application loads. Pretty sure I would use `useEffect` to fetch data first and then replace the context with it.

its either that or just using some cache to store the values without refreshing functionality through api.

in any ways, your method worked, its exactly what I needed! Thank you!